# Python3.1 - Open Opera

Tags: python, browser

I have no idea why this won't work....I'm trying to open opera but it says cannot find runnable browser.

```
op = webbrowser.get('C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\opera.exe')

op.open_new_tab('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
op.open_new_tab('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

The name parameter should just be 'opera':

```
op = webbrowser.get('opera')
```

Make sure you have installed Opera on your computer, and that the executable opera.exe is in the path.

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.get('opera')
<webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x02095490>
```

See the [table of allowed values for the name parameter](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get) in the documentation.

If you want to specify the exact path to the executable (which by the way is a bad idea if you want your application to be portable) then you can specify the command line as follows:

```
op = webbrowser.get(r'C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\opera.exe %s')
```

Comment: Returns "webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser" :/

Comment: @user377419: I assume that you do have Opera installed and on the path, right?

Comment: @THC4k: Works for me in Python 3.1.1.

Comment: On my ActivePython 3.1.2.4 `webbrowser.get('opera')` does not work, while with full path it works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot provide a specific filepath for the browser you want to associate with the webbrowser object. You need to just provide one of a few built-in names. The one you want here is "opera" - see http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/webbrowser.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set the browser path to BROWSER environment variable.

Here's how to do it in Windows (which you are apparently using):
http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm